# Are experience gems useful for anything other than desynthing?

Tags: sequence

I got an experience gem from a battle. If I desynthed it I'd gain 75 XP.However, it seems it's a fairly... unfrequent drop.

Are experience gems useful for purposes other than desynthing? Are they used in recipes and the such?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Short answer: no.

Exp gems are only used for desynthing. I've played the game through twice and never found any recipes that invole these gems. Holding on to them to use the gems later does not do anything either, as their amount will always be absolute and not scale to your level.